# cudaFuncSetCacheConfig - applies to all devices or current device?

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

If I call the `cudaFuncSetCacheConfig` function (which chooses whether I prefer more L1, more shared memory or equal amounts - on Kepler and Maxwell devices) - does it apply to launches of that kernel on all devices on my system, or just the currect one? (API reference doesn't really say)

Comment: It's an attribute of the function.  It applies to that function, regardless of where it is launched.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Please make that an answer and see my edit (I did know it was an attribute of the function - but it could have been a device-specific attribute of the function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cache configuration is a property of the function, not the device. When you call `cudaFuncSetCacheConfig` you are setting it for the module in which the function is contained, and it should then apply to all device contexts into which that module is used.

[This answer assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag]